# Differentiate $\frac{d}{dx}xy^22e^{-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$\frac{d}{dx} xy^2 e^{-x^2}$

I am not sure where to get started and what method I can use to deal with the $x^2$ power

Comment: Do you mean  
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{dx}\left( xy^2 e^{-x^2} \right) = ?
\end{eqnarray*}
Product rule & function of a function ... doddle.

Comment: Is here $y=y(x)$?

Comment: @donaldSplutterwit There’s a negative, no?

Comment: y is a separate variable

Comment: So $$\frac{dy^2}{dx}=0$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)= xy^2 e^{-x^2}$. Then $\ln f = \ln x + 2\ln y - x^2$. Apply $(\ln f)'=f'/f$,

$$\frac{df(x)}{dx} = f(x) ( \frac 1x - 2x )=xy^2 e^{-x^2}( \frac 1x - 2x )= y^2 e^{-x^2}( 1 - 2x^2 )$$

Answer (score 1):

If $u$ is a function of $x$ then derivative of $e^u$ is $u'e^u$ using chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if $y$ is a constant or a function of $x$, which you haven’t clarified yet.

If it’s a constant, this is just simply product rule,
$$\frac{d}{dx}xy^2 2e^{-x^2}=2y^2\left( e^{-x^2}+x\frac{d}{dx}e^{-x^2}\right)=2y^2\left( e^{-x^2}-2x^2e^{-x^2}\right)$$

If $y=y(x)$ then you have to do a bit of 3 term product rule, knowing this:
$$\frac{d}{dx}fgh = \frac{d}{dx}(f)gh + f\frac{d}{dx}(g)h + fg\frac{d}{dx}(h)$$
So
$$\frac{d}{dx}xy^2 2e^{-x^2}=2\left[y^2 e^{-x^2}+x*2yy’e^{-x^2}-x^2y^2e^{-x^2}\right]$$